# Was ist mit "Kabelhochführung" gemeint?

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology

> Die Errichtung der 110/30-kV-Anlage inkl. Kabelhochführung/Kabelendverschluss, des Eigenbedarfes, des Betriebsgebäudes in wärmegedämmter Ausführung einschl. der Infrastruktur

Comment: Was ist unklar? Das Kabel wird wohl vermutlich hoch oben in der Luft, also auf Masten geführt anstatt es in der Erde einzugraben.

Comment: ... oder innerhalb des Gebäudes an der Decke entlang

Comment: Wenn man ein bisschen googled scheint es ein Begriff aus der Hochspannungstechnik zu sein, der den Anschluss an eine Überland Hochspannungsleitung meint.

Comment: Ich weiß weder, was eine Kabelhochführung ist, noch was an der Frage unklar sein soll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Text liest sich wie eine Einzelposition einer Auschreibung bzw. Bauleistungen.

Eigentlich sagt das Wort selbst schon was zu tun ist - das Kabel wird von unten nach oben sachgerecht z.B. in einem Kabelschacht oder an einem Mast nach oben geführt.

Bei 110/30kV werde ich vorsichtshalber keine weiteren Erläuterungen geben.